# open the object in JSON package

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I ran into a problem that I can not have any way to solve. I hope you will understand me better.
My code
GuideFragment.java

```
package ru.yktdevelopers.childrensofasia;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ru.yktdevelopers.childrensofasia.Download_data.download_complete;

public class GuideFragment extends Fragment implements download_complete {

    public ListView list;
    public ArrayList<Countries> countries = new ArrayList<Countries>();
    public ListAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guide_fragment, null);

        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_guide);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        Download_data download_data = new Download_data((download_complete) this);
        download_data.download_data_from_link("http://9142218380.myjino.ru/testfile.json");

        return v;
    }

    public void get_data(String data)
    {
        try {
            JSONArray data_array=new JSONArray(data);

            for (int i = 0 ; i < data_array.length() ; i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(data_array.get(i).toString());

                Countries add=new Countries();
                add.name = obj.getString("country");
                add.code = obj.getString("code");

                countries.add(add);

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Countries {
        String name;
        String code;
    }
}
```

The problem is:
How to make so that she was able to open the object with the name "Test".

JSON File located with http://9142218380.myjino.ru/testfile.json

Comment: [Go to JSON Online Editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=fd603f56abb165b7d2fab65be6fbd821)

Answer (score 0):

replace it with your functions first line after try

```
JSONArray data_array=new JSONArray(new JsonObject(data).getJsonArray("Test"));
```

and pass your whole data from server as string